# nc -zv almacenar salida a un fichero

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, netcat

He buscado como realizar esta acción y no me resulta por ningún lado, estoy haciendo un script que verifica la conexión telnet a unos sitios y requiero agregar en un archivo lo siguiente cuando aplique:

> > Conexion a servidor xxxxx.xxx   [OK]

o

> > Conexión a servidor xxxx.xx [ERROR]

cuando utilizo el comando

```
$ nc -zv mt0.google.com 80
```

me arroja la siguiente respuesta

```
Connection to mt0.google.com 80 port [tcp/http] succeeded!
```

pero si hago lo siguiente en el script

```
    if nc -zv $tlnt 80 | grep -w "succeeded!"; then
        echo -e "$tlnt ==> ${GREEN}[OK]${NONE}"
    else
        echo -e "$tlnt ==> ${RED}[ERROR]${NONE}"
    fi
```

No imprime nada

Para probar el porqué sucedía, traté de enviar la salida del comando a un archivo

```
nc -zv mt0.google.com 80 > resp.txt
Connection to mt0.google.com 80 port [tcp/http] succeeded!
```

al revisar el archivo no contiene nada:

```
:~$ cat resp.txt 
:~$
```

intenté con -o file, pero tampoco me resultó, he buscado en la documentación oficial y sin resultado.

Alguien me podria ayudar a poder guardar la salida de ese comando en un archivo ?

Answer (score 2):

**Nota:** Lo más seguro es que el comando `nc` no esté usando la salida estándar y trato de explicarlo brevemente.

Hay dos tipos de salida en la terminal de Linux:

- stdout: Salida estándar; es a donde la mayoría de programas envían información.
- stderr: Se usa para enviar mensajes de error o de diagnóstico

[Referencia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_input_(stdin)) (En inglés).

Para guardar en un archivo el contenido de la salida estándar:

```
nc -zv mt0.google.com 80 > archivo.txt
```

Para guardar el contenido de error estándar:

```
nc -zv mt0.google.com 80 &> archivo.txt
```

Si quieres redirigir error estándar a salida estándar y capturar ambas:

```
nc -zv mt0.google.com 80 2>&1
```

Pero esto no te permite guardar en archivo, por lo que debes usar el comando [tee](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tee_(Unix)) separando con barra vertical `|`

```
nc -zv mt0.google.com 80 2>&1 | tee archivo.txt
```

Ten en cuenta que estos comandos son para poner el contenido en un archivo, creándolo o sobrescribiéndolo cada vez. Si quieres que se vayan acumulando, en los primeros dos casos reemplaza `>` por `>>` y en el último, agrega la opción `-a` (append o agregar al final):

```
nc -zv mt0.google.com 80 2>&1 | tee -a archivo.txt
```

Te recomiendo leer [esta referencia](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pipelines.html) para tener una idea más amplia sobre el uso de barras verticales AKA *"pipelines"* en bash, que puede resultar útil para resumir el comando con:

```
nc -zv mt0.google.com 80 |& tee archivo.txt
```

Gracias @Cuauhtli por la aclaración.

Comment: Solo para añadir, en algunas shells es posible que el pipe tambien pueda redirigir la salida del error a la salida estandar. Tan solo usar el token "|&":

`nc -zv mt0.google.com 80 |& tee archivo.txt`

Comment: @Cuauhtli, buen punto, esto es muy útil para novatos como tu servidor.

Comment: muchas gracias a ambos, "2>&1" solucionó el problema y con eso ya pude evaluar la salida del comando.